# Is there a jQuery plugin that display like 'title' in an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery to implement a result. when I hover a `<td>` tag that will show some info, and when blur the tag should hide the info. How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/tooltip is most likely what you are looking for. [**demo**](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a tooltip.

There are lot of plugins available

1. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download
2. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/
3. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/tooltip

This article summarized some 30+ plugins:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/